# JEST Testing try catch - get the error message

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test the error handling portion of my function but I am not sure how to do this... I am using someone's API that is always running, so how can I simulate the API not connecting?

```
async function getElephant() {
    const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
    const url = 'https://elephant-api.herokuapp.com/elephants/random'
    fetch(proxyurl + url)
        .then((resp) => { return resp.json() })
        .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((elephant) => {
                const { name, sex, species, note } = elephant
                document.getElementById('name').value = name
                document.getElementById('gender').value = sex
                document.getElementById('species').value = species
                document.getElementById('about').value = note
            })
        })
        // .catch(() => console.log("Can't access " + url + " blocked?"))
        .catch(() => ("Can't access"))
}
```

My test:

```
test('Test .catch block, failure message to connect to url', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    return expect(getElephant()).rejects.toEqual('Can't access');
 })
```

and also tried using fetch-mock utility

```
test('Test .catch block, failure message to connect to url', async () => {
   const url = 'https://lephant-api.herokuapp.com/elephants/random'; //Try misspelling url to catch error

   fetchMock.get(url, {
      status: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify('BAD CONNECTION')
   })

   const response = await getElephant(url)
   const result = await response.json()

   expect(result).toThrow("Can't access")
})
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you how to handle errors with try catch

```js
function addTask() {

  x = "test input";
   
  try { 
    if(x == "")   throw "empty";          // error cases
    if(isNaN(x))  throw "not a number";
      x = Number(x);
    if(x > 10)    throw "too high";
  }
  catch(err) {                          // if there's an error
    console.error("Input is " + err);   // write the error in console
 }
 finally {            // Lets you execute code, after try and catch, regardless of the result
   console.log("Done");              
 }
}

addTask();
```